# Lookup with string using index-match and a wildcard

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a several columns which I want to be automatically filled in based on the prefix of a part name.

An example part name is `1_ANK_retainer_ring`. I have organized all the prefixes in a table. When a user fill in the part name I want the rest of the cells to be filled in automatically by using a wildcard. However this formula doesn't seem to work:

```
=INDEX(Table2[Subsystem];MATCH(Sheet1!E3 & "*";Table2[Part prefix];0))
```

It works fine if I fill in just the prefix or part of the prefix, but as soon as I fill in the entire filename it stop working. What am I missing here?

Below is an example. The 3rd row shows an example of the formula not working. The rest shows what it should look like and is filled in manually.

[image: Bill of materials]

[image: Bill of materials 2]

Comment: are the prefixes all the same length / number of characters?

Comment: @WhiteHat yes they are but not quite sure if they will stay like that forever

Comment: when there is only the prefix in `Table2[Part prefix]` it can't work with full name (having just `{aa,ba,ca}` how is it supposed to find `ba_33`?)

Comment: @pnuts I have updated my question with relevant images

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=INDEX(Table2[Subsystem];MATCH(LEFT(E3; 6) & "*";Table2[Part prefix];0))
```

@pnuts i simply started with the code that was shown at the beginning... however... asuming *a lot* the formulas

```
C3: =LOOKUP(LEFT(E3; 6);Table2[Part prefix];Table2[Category])
D3: =LOOKUP(LEFT(E3; 6);Table2[Part prefix];Table2[Subsystem])
```

should also work  ;)

Comment: @pnuts to use it in one step `MATCH( , ,0)` needs an exact match, but looking for "2_S" (not having the full string) will still find a match cus of the `*`... it is just useless for the case that `C:C` holds more characters then the prefix, but the question has not excluded this case... so i keept my `*` :)

Comment: @pnuts the only formula shown was with `;` as seperator... so i used them too :)

Comment: @pnuts thanks for the hint with comma and `LEFT`... as said: asuming *a lot*: having always a astring that holds at least 6 characters... just looking at the first picture, it is always like `"prefix"&"_"&partname"` => always the full prefix is used... would be a *short* answer... at least the OP has some different formulas to pick one from :D

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*, in C3 of Sheet1 and copied across to D3 and from there down:

```
=INDEX(Table2[Category];MATCH(LEFT(Table1[[Part Name]:[Part Name]];6);Table2[[Part prefix]:[Part prefix]];0))
```